# save input and output data has passed in adb

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection, adb

i want save all input and output commands has executed in adbd I tried to pull adbd file in sbin folder and extract it to modify and Implement of the idea to write a few lines for create file and do fopen function to store input and output data in file which was created But the adbd is encoded :( Please give me some ideas which I can record all input and output commands.

Comment: What is adbd and how are the commands run?

Comment: either the [Android debug bridge or the advanced debugger or the Apple Desktop Bus](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4978/rename-adb-to-android-adb), depending on who you ask.